# can you use the ternary operators with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, operators, ternary

I have used a bit of jQuery to fire an if function. When I try to simplify the equation using vanilla javascript's ternary operands it doesn't seem to work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
if(windowBottom > objectBottom) {

    $(this).animate({opacity: '1'}, 1500);
    $(this).addClass('item-play__right');
}
//works fine

windowBottom > objectBottom ? $(this).animate({opacity: '1'}, 1500).addClass('item-play__right');
//doesn't work
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write this ternary operator with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595585/how-to-write-this-ternary-operator-with-jquery)

Comment: Don't use ternary operator instead of `if ..else`, use the operator only where it's expected, i.e. inside an expression.

Comment: Questioning if you know what a ternary operator is, based on your *doesn't work* example.  What did you expect it to do?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done but it requires usage of both `?` & `:`

```
windowBottom > objectBottom ? ($(this).animate({opacity:"1"}, 
1500).addClass("item-play__right")) :'';
```

Without ternary operator the snippet can also be written as

```
windowBottom > objectBottom && ($(this).animate({opacity:"1"}, 
1500).addClass("item-play__right"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid ternary syntax you're using, there should be two possible outcome separated by a `:` character.

Also, if you're using itfor side-effects and not to compute a value, it is better to use an if/ else

Answer (score 0):

You need both `?` and `:` otherwise it will result in syntax error.

```
windowBottom > objectBottom ? $(this).animate({opacity: '1'}, 1500).addClass('item-play__right') : "";
```